# What is an alternative option to Audience Builder in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, filters, data-designer, audience

**Our goal** is to allow users within SFMC platform to be able to create audience / segmentation with drag and drop options (even if users are non-technical and got no experience with SQL).

**Current state:** Our contact database includes a number of tables (not just one master table) and each table got different kind of relationship with main contacts table (like one-to-one and one-to-many in some cases).

**Future state:** Goal was to look into audience builder since it allows joining multiple tables easily and segmentation can be created easily but recently I read online that audience builder is being retired in SFMC.

It seems like recommendation is to use SFMC filters but when contact datable consists of multiple tables, it can be quite tedious work to create so many filters and joining multiple tables in filters is quite a lot of work.

**Question:** Is there any recommendation how non-technical users can create segmentations easily? Is there any alternative to audience builder within SFMC?

Comment: I think the easiest approach would be to try [DE SELECT](https://deselect.com/). I am not affiliated with them, but have heard positive feedback from people using it

Comment: Hi @LukasLunow thanks for the suggestion. Got it, this sounds like a good  3rd party app option if we plan to go that route. Considering what options are available within SFMC, any suggestions based on the use-case described above?

Comment: You will not be getting anything from Marketing Cloud outside of the options you have mentioned, as you indeed only have Query Activities and Filtered Data Extensions available. If you want to do more user friendly segmentation, there is only DE Select, or [Salesforce Data Cloud](https://www.salesforce.com/products/genie/overview/) - but the latter provides much more features than just segmentation and might be slightly overkill for your use case.

Comment: Thank you @LukasLunow for the recommended, it is helpful